# How can i locate element using ngweb driver?

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to click a button from a angular page.I am using ng web driver as below:

```
driver.findElement(ByAngular.partialButtonText("LAUNCH")).click();
//Actual launch button
```

but it shows no such element how can i proceed to get that element

Answer (score 0):

With the minimal information provided on the question: You might want to switch to the angular frame before finding the element.

Answer (score 0):

With the minimal information provided on the question: You might want to switch to the angular frame before finding the element. 
Or try waiting for the page to load completely with SyncPage(); or  Thread.Sleep(1000);